# Why Kendo validation won't let me through no matter if checkbox is checked or not

Tags: asp.net, validation, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with validating checkboxes. No matter if checkbox is checked or not, Kendo validation says that this field is empty. I cannot get it working anyway.
Here is my grid for example:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<ConfigurationModel>()
    .Name("ConfigurationGrid")
    .Columns(column =>
     { column.Bound(model => model.IsChecked)
             .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsChecked ? 'checked=checked' : '' # disabled='disabled'></input>")
             .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true))
             .Title("Is Checked");})
```

I am using fluent validation and have a validator, but not a word in it about checkbox.

Comment: Solved this problem. Needed to remove 'required' attribute of this field in js like     $("#IsChecked").removeAttr("data-val").removeAttr("data-val-required");